# Connectors on ARGB strip confuse me

Tags: led-strip, rgb

I am looking for a nice ARGB strip for a project of mine.  I am quite familiar with the 3 pads concept for ground, data and power, but a lot of the strips that I'm looking into buying have multiple connectors already soldered on them even if they are the right kind of strips with 3 pads.

[Here is an example](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000875413944.html)

It seems like there is a 3 pin connector plus 2 wires. How do I use these strips?

Comment: Have you asked the supplier? My guess it is just a daisy-chain.

Comment: These two extra cables are usually for inserting power in the middle or at the end of an LED strip. When you have a long LED strips (several meters), the resistance of the copper traces in the strip itself is relatively large and will  cause the voltage to drop at the end of an LED strip, causing the LEDs at the end of the strip to become dimmer or malfunction. The two extra leads are there for creating one or more additional, low-resistance, paths to supply the middle and/or the end of a long strip.

Comment: The 2 wires are just extra power/ground wires